# How to leave useful information in the windows event viewer

Tags: c#, crash

When a program crash, you can usually see that evidence in the windows event viewer. However although sometimes useful, some other times the information in it is quite cryptic.

I have written a program in C# and it sometimes crashed. I have corrected it but I would like to leave some info that can help me debug it if it crashes in the future.

Is there a way that I can leave some useful information (like exception type, line where it crash etc) to the event viewer, by adding something to the code?

Comment: Please update your question to show an example of your current unhelpful message, and another helpful message that you are aiming for.

Comment: Usually a stack trace is useful for debugging.

Comment: We use a logging framework to log messages to the event viewer. Log4net, NLog, or there are many others.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your own logger, when you get an exception, you can write to the eventlog. Here is a small example.

```
 string cs = "YourIdentifier";

if (!EventLog.SourceExists(cs))
   EventLog.CreateEventSource(cs, "Application");    

EventLog.WriteEntry(cs, "YourMessage", EventLogEntryType.Error);
```

Comment: In the documentation, it says that the source can not be used immediately after creation and the application should be run a second time...